# google analytics api query a specific url

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am accessing the Google analytics API with PHP which works on my end but I'd love to filter the results a bit further.
Right now I am using:

```
$OBJresult = $analytics -> data_ga -> get(
    'ga:' . $profilID,
    '2012-01-01',
    date( "Y-m-d" ),
    'ga:visits',
    array(
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => '25'
    )
);
```

Currently this returns a set of 25 pages sorted by its hits.
I would love to restrict the results to a specific path within the server. So e.g. only query domain.com/news and only see what the most hit news pages are.
I can filter with PHP but rather have the query as specific as possible.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the `filters` option.

```
$OBJresult = $analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:' . $profilID,
    '2012-01-01',
    date("Y-m-d"),
    'ga:visits',
    array(
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/news',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => '25'
    )
);
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/pagetracking) for the list of page tracking dimensions you can filter on.

Comment: thank you! I actually found using the `==` insteat of `=@` works better for me but same problem here: can I filter the absolute address? so `domain.com/interviews/article/news` would not be found in the result for `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/news',`?

Comment: `==` should be an exact match, `=@` looks for anything that contains the expression. See https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#filterOperators for all the operators you can use in filters.

Comment: yeah well thats the problem. this now returns nothing as /news alone is not a page but `domain.com/news/something` is.... so I guess I am looking for something like `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/news*',`

Comment: `=~` seems promising... :)

Comment: ended up using `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=~^/news/',`  thanks again!

Comment: You might also want to look at `ga:pagePathLevel1`, which just matches the first directory of the path.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the filters string to say "if path includes /news" which can be done as follows:

```
$OBJresult=$analytics->data_ga->get(
    'ga:'.$profilID,
    '2012-01-01',
    date("Y-m-d"),
    'ga:visits',
    array(
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=@/news',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageviews',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => '25'));
```

The answer supplied by Barmar will only find an exact match for the /news page.

Comment: thats it really. thanks! though this will look into the url and find all urls that have "/news" in its path. domain.com/news/article and domain.com/interviews/article/news alike... is there a way to limit to `domain.com/news/`?

Answer (score 0):

Reporting V4 example that may be useful. Thank god for these queries, their objects and poor documentation can cause severe ass cancer..

```
function segmentRequest(&$analyticsreporting) {

$query = [
        "viewId" => "XXXXXXX",
        "dateRanges" => [
            "startDate" => "2018-02-01",
            "endDate" => "2018-02-15"
        ],
        "metrics" => [
            "expression" => "ga:pageviews"
        ],
        "dimensions" => [
            "name" => "ga:pagepath"
        ],
        "dimensionFilterClauses" => [
            'filters' => [
                "dimension_name" => "ga:pagepath",
                "operator" => "EXACT",
                "expressions" => "/en/some_cool_page.php"
            ]
        ]
    ];

  // Call the batchGet method.
  $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
  $body->setReportRequests( array( $query) );
  $response = $analyticsreporting->reports->batchGet( $body );

  printResults($response->getReports());
}
```