# How to filter by URI path in Google Analytics API

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to get some Google Analytics data (number of page views) (API V3) filtered with `ga:pagePath`.

Firstly I connect to API with the following code:

```
$token = "some token";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("***");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setDeveloperKey($developer_key);
$client->setScopes(array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"));
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAccessToken($token);
```

Then I get all accounts with their respective profiles (views):

```
$service = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);               
$accounts = $service->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();

$profiles = new stdClass();

foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $item) {

    foreach($item->getWebProperties() as $wp) {  
        $views = $wp->getProfiles();

        if (!is_null($views)) {

            foreach($wp->getProfiles() as $view) {
                $profiles->{$view['id']} = $view['name'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After I got all profiles (views) I get the data:

```
$path = "/example-path/path-example";
$host = "www.example.com";

$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath,ga:source,ga:keyword',
    'sort' => '-ga:sessions,ga:source',
    'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic,ga:pagePath=='.$path.',ga:hostname=='.$host,
    'max-results' => '25'
);

$totalSessions = 0;

$today = date('Y-m-d', time());
$monthbefore = date('Y-m-d', (time() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60)));

foreach ($profiles as $profile_id => $profile) {
    $data = $service->data_ga->get(
                "ga:".$profile_id,
                $monthbefore,
                $today,
                'ga:sessions',
                $optParams
             );

    $totalSessions += intval($data->totalsForAllResults['ga:sessions']);
}

if (!isset($analytics_data)) {
    $analytics_data = new stdClass();
}

if (!isset($analytics_data->$ii)) {
    $analytics_data->$ii = new stdClass();
}

$analytics_data->$ii->{'total_page_views'} = $totalSessions;
```

And now I get the data. But the problem is I get the total number of page views for the whole website while I need the number of page views for a page with the particular path "/example-path/path-example". I cannot figure out where exactly I am missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This thread should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728093/google-analytics-api-query-a-specific-url).

Comment: you might also want to check out e.g., today, yesterday, or NdaysAgo where N is a positive integer.  for your dates its easer.