# How to get organic pageViews and organicSearches for a specific URL via google-analytics-api?

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I need to iterate over a large number of urls via google-analytics-api (PHP) and fetch different metrics like pageViews, bounceRate and organicSearches.

To fetch these I tried the following which is also explained here:
[google analytics api query a specific url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728093/google-analytics-api-query-a-specific-url)

```
$data = $service->data_ga->get(
    "ga:".$targetId,
    '2014-08-10',
    date("Y-m-d"),
    "ga:users,ga:sessions",
    array(
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$url.', ga:medium==organic',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageViews, ga:bounceRate, ga:avgSessionDuration, ga:organicSearches',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => '25'
    )
);
```

I also read that you have to specify "ga:medium" to be able to fetch the "organic" traffic. But combining these two values (pagePath and medium) leads to a Google-Service-Exception saying "Invalid value 'ga:medium==organic, ga:pagePath==URL' for filters parameter. 
After removing the "ga:medium==organic" parameter it works and fetches all parameters - except organicSearches" which remains null.

How can I combine the specific pagePath and the organic parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the space between

```
ga:medium==organic, ga:pagePath==URL
```

Reason being with a space it will get encoded to %20 and not be valid, and you probably mean AND which is represented by a ; and not OR which is a , between them.

[GA Reporting API reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#AND)

So your filter should read:

```
ga:medium==organic;ga:pagePath==URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you. Only replace

```
'filters' => 'ga:pagePath=='.$url.'  to   `'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/page-slug',` .
```

and your code becomes

```
$data = $service->data_ga->get(
    "ga:".$targetId,
    '2014-08-10',
    date("Y-m-d"),
    "ga:users,ga:sessions",
    array(
        'filters' => 'ga:pagePath==/page-slug', ga:medium==organic',
        'dimensions' => 'ga:pagePath',
        'metrics' => 'ga:pageViews, ga:bounceRate, ga:avgSessionDuration, ga:organicSearches',
        'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        'max-results' => '25'
    )
);
```